# Open list of websites from text file, in the same tab

Tags: shell

I'm busy with some demo that should open some websites from a text file, one after the other. It should open each website in the same tab, than wait for an amount of time before it loads the text line of the text file, so to load the next website. After finishing it should start again.

So lets say:

Start script... opens google... wait 30 seconds... opens facebook... wait 30 seconds... opens whatever... wait 30 seconds... and so on... EOV=start at the beginning.

Language is not important, so Batch, VBS, PS, or whatever is available on a Windows 7 system. I don't mind installing something else, if necessary.

Comment: Sounds like a something that would be implemented as a browser extension. A quick search brought up [such an extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/rotisserie-url-rotator/iljemanjjfjlglhkmojkmfbpphiaheja?hl=en) for Chrome.

Comment: Another approach would be to write a script that generates an HTML file with a page-filling iframe. You could take your input file and insert the entries into a JavaScript array in the page. That array would be stepped through and the iframe src URL would be changed to the current entry in the list.

Comment: Didn't know something like that exists. Thanks, i'll have a try.

Answer (score 0):

I would to do this with `perl` + `Firefox & MozRepl`:

Firefox

- install the [MozRepl](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-Us/firefox/addon/mozrepl/) addon
- start the `MozRepl` plugin in the `Firefox`'s `Tools` menu

perl

- install [Strawberry Perl](http://strawberryperl.com)
- configure the `cpan` command
- install the [WWW::Mechanize::Firefox](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Mechanize::Firefox) module

after, the solution is an easy perl script, let say: `openurls.pl`

```
#!perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use WWW::Mechanize::Firefox;

my $mech = WWW::Mechanize::Firefox->new( activate => 1, tab => 'current' );
while(<>) {
    chomp;
    $mech->get($_);
    sleep(30);
}
```

Usage:

- start Firefox
- use the script as: `perl openurls.pl < myurls.txt`

Ps: never used windows yet - so maybe me missed something...